# The number of spacing $k$ non-attacking towers on the board $\left\{(i,j):1 \le i \le j \le n \right\}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that the number of spacing $k$ non-attacking towers on the board: $$\left\{(i,j):1 \le i \le j \le n \right\}$$ is equal: $$\left\{\begin{matrix} n+1\\n+1-k\end{matrix}\right\}.$$

This board e.g. for $5$ looks like this:
[image]
Unfortunately, in this case I can not give any observations to the exercise, because I completely fell over how I can go about them and I have no imagination to consider this problem. I know only what this board looks like.
Can I ask you for some tips on what to look for to start this task?
Thank you in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Do you mean rooks by towers? And do you mean a chess board which is 8x8?(Like the usual one)

Comment: Hint: In how many places can you put the first one? Then the second one? And so on

Comment: @miraunpajaro I think the OP does mean rooks, but "$i\le j$" means that the "chessboard" is triangular.

Comment: @bof I see, I don't think it matters that much though.

Comment: @miraunpajaro Depends on what you mean by "that much". Your hint makes sense for the square board, not somuch for the triangle. IIf $n=3$ there are $6$ places to put the first rook. How many places are there for the second rook??

Comment: @miraunpajaro The German word for a rook (in chess) is "Turm", which in real (non-chess) life means tower.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Same thing in Spanish, I just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by induction (by $k$).
I left base of induction for you.

### Induction step

From Stirling number properties we know identity:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} n\\i\end{matrix}\right\} = i \cdot \left\{\begin{matrix} n-1\\i\end{matrix}\right\} + \left\{\begin{matrix} n-1\\i-1\end{matrix}\right\} $$

Our cheeseboard is just triangle.

We have:
$$(n-(k-1)) \cdot \left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-(k-1)\end{matrix}\right\} + \left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-k\end{matrix}\right\} $$

### Explanation:

$(n-(k-1)) \cdot \left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-(k-1)\end{matrix}\right\}$ - if we put $1$ rook (tower) in top row - then we choose our place in $(n-(k-1))$ ways and from induction rest of rooks put in $\left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-(k-1)\end{matrix}\right\}$ ways 
$\left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-k\end{matrix}\right\}$ - if we don't put k'th rook (tower) to top row, we should put all $k$ rooks in our triangle without top row.
This gives us:
$$(n-(k-1)) \cdot \left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-(k-1)\end{matrix}\right\} + \left\{\begin{matrix} n\\n-k\end{matrix}\right\} = \left\{\begin{matrix} n+1\\n+1-k\end{matrix}\right\} $$